# jQuery mobile getting wrong authentication

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-mobile, mysqli

I have the following situation:

index.html (which is my login page)

```
<div data-role="page" id="page_login">
<div id="wrapper_top_image">
   <div id="top_image"></div>
</div>
<div data-role="content" data-theme="b">    
    <div id="landmark-1" data-landmark-id="1">
    <form id="loginForm" onsubmit="return submitLogin();">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username" />
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submitButton">
    </form>
</div>      
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>&copy; 2013 Company</h4>
    <h6>Developed by Alex</h6>
</div>
```

and then my PHP Script that is going to check everything -> ps.. I fixed to avoid injection already! :

auth.php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_hostname,$mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);

// Parse the log in form if the user has filled it out and pressed "Log In"
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {

    $username =$_POST['username'];
    $password =$_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT id, password, username FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die( $mysqli->error() );
    $rowN= mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($rowN==1){
       $response_array['status'] = 'success'; 
    } else {
       $response_array['status'] = 'error'; 
    }
    echo json_encode($response_array);

}
$mysqli->close();
```

Finally my JQuery Script:

```
function submitLogin(){ 
 jQuery.support.cors = true; 
 $.ajax({ 
     url: 'http://www.xxxx.com/mobile/auth.php',
     crossDomain: true,
     type: "post",
     data: $("#loginForm").serialize(), 
     success: function(data){
         if(data.status == 'success'){
             //alert("Granted Access!");
             $.mobile.changePage("main.html");  
         }else if(data.status == 'error'){
             alert("Authentication Invalid. Please try again!");
             navigator.app.exitApp();
             $.mobile.changePage("index.html");       
        }

     }
 }); 
};
```

Everything is working ok! Data is checked and if it is okay, is redirected to main.html (main page) otherwise the app pops up a window saying that the authentication is wrong, keeping the user in the same page.

Here is the dilemma: If users type the wrong credential trying to login again, any credential that he/she enter will be considerate invalid even if he/she entered the right one and the app will keep going back to the login page until I refresh the browser or end the app in case of running in the device.

Does anyone knows what may be happening?

Comment: Hmm check your HTTP requests and see what it is actually posting to the PHP script.. your code appears valid. You said that you "fixed to avoid injection".. What changes did you make to the script? Are you using parameterized queries now?

Comment: @Your, knock it off with the meta tagging, please.  If you feel a question should be closed, then vote for it to be closed and/or downvote.  There is a custom close reason field available under the Off Topic category.

Comment: @Charles I'd be glad to submit if you ask me to do something sensible or useful. BTW, bubbling up pointless questions just spam the list. Why not just let it go?